# Set default value for attributes of 3rd party blazor components

Tags: blazor

I've a 3rd party libray which has a AdvancedButton component.
AdvancedButton component has an attribute as followings:

```
<AdvancedButton Task="@AdvancedButtonTask.Send" />
```

AdvancedButtonTask is an enum with values such as Send, Delete etc.

I've no access to its code and I'd like to set default value of that attribute to something.

I'm not interested in inheriting that component, and I'd like to have something like XAML styles.

In xaml styles I can write followings:

```
<Style TargetType="AdvancedButton">
   <Setter Property="Method" Value="Send"
</Style>
```

and if I put that style in application's global style, I'm good to go.

Note that in my tests, I was able to style html based attributes in css/scss

If I was able to style native blazor component attributes in scss, It was good enough for me too.

Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is at all possible without writing your own component. The best solution in my opinion would be to create your own component.

You could call it something like `AdvancedDefaultButton`, and this component can then call the other component and supply it with default values.